# problem with convert like function in oracle / doctrine

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine

In oracle there is a "convert" function to convert from one encoding to other. I wrote custom function for doctrine (converting column from ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DQL;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
class ConvertFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $stringPrimary;

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return $sqlWalker->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->getUpperExpression(
            "CONVERT(".$sqlWalker->walkSimpleArithmeticExpression($this->stringPrimary).", 'EE8ISO8859P2', 'UTF8')"
        );
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->stringPrimary = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

when I use it, it doesn't search anything, but when I run sql in DB it works.

Does symfony / doctrine change a variable encoding ?

edit:

(my custom function is declared as convertToISO8859): When I run (in symfony):

```
select * from tables where convertToISO8859(name) = 'Jesień'
```

It return nothing, but in symfony profiler it shows properly sql:

```
select * from tables where upper(convert(name), 'EE8ISO8859P2', 'UTF8') = 'Jesień'
```

Comment: Since your php script will likely use UTF-8 it might be that the input conversion is working on an already converting string. I think the best way to figure this out is to check the SQL that was being sent. You can find the query in your dev.log, the doctrine tab in the profiler toolbar or by exctrating it manually from the SQL-Logger in the EntityManager.

Comment: I did it, sql is ok (when I run it, it shows results)

Comment: I don't mean running the SQL manually, I mean the actual query produced by Doctrine, including the input - i.e. whether the provided parameter has the correct encoding -, and the result Doctrine gets back.

Comment: yes, it's ok...:(

Comment: What do you mean it's ok? Does it return the data you expect? How do you use the query in yor code? Is there maybe an Exception that is being caught?

Comment: I just edited question

Comment: Your query has a call to `upper()` in there. Could that cause the issue? Are you sure the query is sent as UTF-8? What charset did you configure in your doctrine dbal settings?

Comment: dbal is configurated as EEISO8859P2, and symfony as UTF8, that's why I doing that "converting thing":).. if upper could do issue, then why when copying that SQL to DB it runs, here (in symfony) not?

Comment: Your custom query looks like SQL, but the function is DQL. I would expect your custom query to look something like `SELECT e.* FROM App\Entity\MyEntity e WHERE convertToISO8859(e.name) = 'Jesién'`. Are you sure you are using it correctly?

Comment: dump($qb->getQuery()->getDQL()); returns SELECT e FROM App\Entity\MyEntity e WHERE convertToISO8859(e.name) = 'Jesién'

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what's wrong then. Maybe someone else can help. Could you add the code that uses the query? That might be useful as well.